# Getting record count using Anko SQLite in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, anko

Currently learning Kotlin and translating an app for iOS, this includes running queries on a SQLite database, I am using the Anko SQLite extensions to run the queries for example to run "SELECT * FROM QuoteType" I am using

```
val quoteTypes = database.use {
        select(QuoteType.TABLE_NAME).exec { parseList(classParser<QuoteType>()) }
    }
```

I am struggling to figure out to run SELECT COUNT(recordId) FROM QuoteType

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Stuart

Comment: did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was declare a data class to hold the result

```
data class recordCountObject(val returnCount: Long)
```

and then use the normal raw SQL query

```
val quoteTypeCount = database.use {
            query<recordCountObject>("select count(*) AS returnCount FROM QuoteType")
        }
```

This gives me the binding back to a concrete object

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-SQLite#querying-data) you should call `select` with additional column `"count(recordId)"`. You can do it by passing additional String argument to `select` method or, using the query builder, by calling `column("count(recordId)")` on object returned by `select` method.

Answer (score 0):

why not using 

   `val quoteTypeCount = database.use { query("your_table", arrayOf("*"), null, null, null, null, null,null).count
}`

quoteTypeCount alway return Int as record count